# Making two Http request synchronously in Angular 7

Tags: rxjs, angular7, angular2-observables

I am new to Angular/RxJS etc. I want to make two HTTP requests sequentially. I assumed if I call the next method in the complete function of first observable it should run sequentially, but that is not the case.

```
login(): boolean {
let windowsAuthToken: string;

var result = this.http.get(this.authUrl).subscribe(
  (response: any) => {
    windowsAuthToken = response.token;
  },
  err => {},
  () => {
    return this.performWindowsAuthentication(windowsAuthToken);
  }
);
return false;
}

performWindowsAuthentication(windowsAuthToken: string): boolean {
if (!!windowsAuthToken) {
  const loginRequest = new WindowsLoginRequest(windowsAuthToken);
  this.http
    .post<WindowsLoginRequest>(this.winLoginUrl, loginRequest)
    .subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        if (response) {
          localStorage.setItem(Constants.jwtToken, response.jwt);
        }
      },
      err => this.logger.logError("Failed to get JWT token", err),
      () => {
        return true;
      }
    );
  } else {
      return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one observable with switchMap

```
this.http.get(this.authUrl).pipe(
  map(response => response.token),
  switchMap(token => this.http.post<WindowsLoginRequest>(this.winLoginUrl, new WindowsLoginRequest(token)))
)
```

Comment: Ok, so if the original token request failed then how will I get the error? Also how do I check that switchmap should only be called  if original request was a success.

Comment: "Also how do I check that switchmap should only be called if original request was a success." It will be. About getting error, add `catchError` before `map` in the pipe.

Comment: you can tap before the map and add an error handler to the original stream and then add a filter after the tap to only allow valid responses through